# PHP composer not autoloading class

Tags: php, composer-php

Here is my index.php file:

```
<?php

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use Core\Router;

$router = new Router();
```

And my `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "root/php-project",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Core\\": "core/"
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my project tree:

```
- core\router.php
- index.php
- composer.json
```

I did `composer dump-autoload -o` but the class is not loading. It throws me `Class "Core\Router" not found` error. What did I do wrong? Please helep me.

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference - can you try naming the file with `Router.php` so the case matches the name of your class.

Comment: That worked actually. @NigelRen

Comment: Is there a way to make composer autoload case insensitive or something?

Comment: The duplicate may help.  BUT (I've already mentioned this morning) its worth using the correct case always in PHP and MySQL

Comment: Gotcha @NigelRen